# Проблема с импортом в Java - unable to resolve class

Tags: java, maven, импорт

Использую Grails в приложении. Подключил Maven через

```
grails create-pom
```

Убрал из pom часть build так как с ней приложение при запуске бросало ошибки

Добавил hystrix зависимость для реализации Circuit-Breaker, депендеси подтянулись

```
 <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
```

В чем конкретно сейчас проблема:

Делаю импорт, все ок

```
import com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.annotation.HystrixCommand
import org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.EnableCircuitBreaker
```

Но при запуске приложения выбрасывает Compilation error: startup failed: unable to resolve class с указанием моих импортируемых классов.

С чем может быть связано?

Попробовал другую стороннюю библиотеку jsoup, на нее тоже ругается.

Comment: Как запускаете?

Comment: как grails run-app

Comment: А вы уверены что в вашем грейлс конфиге зависимости так же прописаны?

Comment: нет, можно линк на прописывание зависимостей grails

Comment: Не знаю какая у вас версия, но искать где-то тут: http://docs.grails.org/2.3.7/guide/conf.html

Comment: Вроде решил проблему чтением английского  stack owerflow

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, можно ли настроить связку Maven-Grails так чтобы зависимости привязывались автоматически... но в моем случае Maven выполнял что от него и требовалось, просто закачивал jar во внешнюю библиотеку, но по умолчанию grails оттуда не тянет информацию, в отличие от идеи, которая библиотеку видела и говорила что все ок, файлы есть.
В общем я открыл путь в эксплорере к нужному jar. И скопировал этот файл прямо в проект projectName\lib\

После этого в консоли прописал "чит"

```
grails compile --refresh-dependencies
```

После этого все заработало

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215351/how-to-add-java-jar-files-to-grails-project  это ссылка по которой я подчерпнул информацию. Там описываются и другие способы привязки зависимостей, кому интересно ознакомьтесь. Но вероятнее всего после любого из способов надо будет применить описанный выше "чит"